# Creating a editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to understand object inheritance in JS with an exercise, create a online editor, like this one that i'm writing on.

But.. i'm a little confuse here, i want use data-* to manipulate my editor:

```
<div class="editor__wrapper">
 <div data-editor="toolbar">
 </div>
 <textarea data-editor="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

So, i was trying initialize like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
 $('[data-editor]').each(function() {
  var element = $(this);

   var editor = new Editor(element);
 });
});
```

and the editor:

```
var Editor = function(element) {
 this.element = element;
};
```

But this is not what i exactly want here..

I want initialize with data-* but create a toolbar if is a toolbar and create an editor if is an editor, but make the two inherit from the a father with commum properties.

I'm little lost here, what you guys think about this? There is a better way???

Thanks.

Comment: `var element = $(this); if(element.data('editor') === "toolbar") { var toolbar = new Toolbar(element); } else { var editor = new Editor(element); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to setup the Editor to handle which to create depending on the value, you can perform the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('[data-editor]').each(function() {
            var element = $(this);

            var editor = new Editor(element);
        });
    });
    var Editor = function(element) {
        this.element = element;
        switch(element.data("editor")){
            case "toolbar":
                // Do something magic
                console.log("toolbar");
                break;
            case "editor":
                // Do something less magic
                console.log("editor");
                break;
            default:
                // Be sad and lonely
                console.log("lonely");
                break;
        }
    };
</script>
```

This doesn't help with object inheritance in JS though.  For that you would need to do prototyping and that gets ... complicated.  You can see examples here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance